# Written to a log file managed by java from a procedure Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, logging

Can be written to a log file managed by java from a procedure Oracle PL / SQL

For example:

> It updates or inserts on equipment if it has both records necessary If
>   is missing a record is inserted a message in the log file ('logs \
>   application \ Flux_JJMMAAAA.log').

Thx.

Comment: You need to give us more details about what you are trying to achieve.  Otherwise this question will get closed as NARQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be these two documentation links might be helpful

[Diagnosability in JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm)

[FileHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html)